# How to understand previous (Form1.cs) data information

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, entity

I have some code for when user double cell click to Datagridview ı call this function :

```
public void GoBackMain()
        {
            if (dgvCariRehber.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                cariModel.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCariRehber.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value);
                using (Entities db = new Entities())
                {
                    frmMain main = new frmMain();
                    cariModel = db.xcaSabits.Where(x => x.Id == cariModel.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    main.lblCariID.Text = cariModel.Id.ToString(); // cariSabitte güncelleme için id yi gönder.
                    main.txtCariKodu.Text = cariModel.cariKodu;

                    main.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
        }
```

but ı want to go another form if previous form open this. not go only main.form. how can ı do this form section parametric ?

Answer (score 0):

On that form create a public property like :
`public IForm Caller { get; set; } = main;`
Then just before you call the current form set that property with the form that you are calling from with something like `formWithGridOn.Caller = this;
formWithGridOn.Show();
this.Hide();`
You would then need to change the code you have listed above to be `Caller.Show(); this.Hide()`

I think the interface is IForm but that needs to be the interface for the form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okey but if ı have 2 forms to return how can ı catch data of previous form ? ıf ı have Caller2 ?

Comment: Same principle,  create a property that can store the data in and then the destination can call back to get it.

Comment: how to formWithGridOn form understand which form is coming ?

Comment: ı cannot do Caller.lblID and Caller2.lblID same time. The function don't understand and if blocks pass true

Comment: The calling form sets the property Caller to itself. This means the called form has a reference to the form that called it.